# Що означає слово перев'янець?

Tags: значення-слів

Шукаючи відповідь на попереднє запитання натрапила у колядці *[«По горі, горі павоньки ходять»](http://proridne.com/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96/index%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%9F.html)* на цікаве слово, значення якого не можу знайти:

> Лише ймили вінець-бав’янець.
>
> — А що нам буде за **перев’янець**?

Ані в [Словнику української мови в 11 т](http://sum.in.ua/s/perev.janecj), ані в [Етимологічному словнику української мови](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) немає цього слова.  В іншому варіанті цієї колядки [«ПО ГОРІ, ГОРІ ПАВА ЛІТАЛА»](http://proridne.com/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96/index%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%9F.htm) знаходжу **переємець**.
  В [Українському тлумачному словнику](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/116450/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C):

> **переємець**
>       -мця, ч., діал.
>
> Той, хто переймає щось.

Чи **перев'янець=переємець**? Якщо так, то яке значення ці слова мають у *колядці?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так, це слово подається в однакових контекстах, але різними словами. Для порівняння ще знову сюди кину:

1. **["ПО ГОРІ, ГОРІ ПАВА ЛІТАЛА"](http://proridne.com/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96/%D0%9F%D0%9E_%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%86,_%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%86_%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%92%D0%90_%D0%9B%D0%86%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%90.html)**:

   > — Ой ми го найшли, ми го возьмили.

> А що ж нам буде за **переємець**?
>
> — Вой добрий же вам переєм буде.
>
> Одному буде шовк-хустиночка,
>
> Шовк-хустиночка на завиваннє.
>
> Другому буде золот перстенець,
>
> Золот перстенець на средний палець.
>
> Третьому буде сама молода,
>
> Сама молода а як ягода.

**2. [ПО ГОРІ, ГОРІ ПАВОНЬКИ ХОДЯТЬ](http://proridne.com/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96/%D0%9F%D0%9E_%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%86,_%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%86_%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%AC%D0%9A%D0%98_%D0%A5%D0%9E%D0%94%D0%AF%D0%A2%D0%AC.html)**:

> — А що нам буде за **перев’янець**?
>
> Одному буде вінець-бав’янець,
>
> Другому буде — злотий перстенець,
>
> Третьому буде — сама молода,
>
> Сама молода чом Марусенька.
>
> Вінець-бав’янець — лиш по обідець,
>
> Золотий перстенець — лиш по обідець,
>
> Сама молода — до конца віка.

Ймовірно, що, як пише у **[Російсько-українському народному сучасному словнику 2009](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)**, переємець - "спадок":

> Преемник, преемница – насту́пник, насту́пниця, (наследник) ***спадкоє́мець***, спадкоє́мниця; (продолжатель) продовжувач, продовжувачка; (редко) **переємець**

У статті **[КУПАЙЛО — БОГ ПЛОДЮЧОСТІ, ЛЮБОВІ, ВЕСЕЛОЩІВ](http://dnevnik.bigmir.net/groups/article/53564)** знаходжу ще й доволі цікаву інформацію:

> Дівочі вінки, пущені на воду, переймали хлопці. На Полтавщині такого хлопця називали «**ПЕРЕЄМЕЦЬ**» - **наречений**.

Тобто наречений - це переємець, адже він перейняв вінок, який пустила дівчина по другий бік рік і одружився саме з нею; перейняв вінок, а з нею і її.

Щодо конкретного поданого Вами тексту, то тут, можливо, при записуванні збирачем тексту в інформанта виник одрук: **перев’янець <-- переємець**.

Щодо другого слова, то ***що буде за переємець* = *що буде у спадок***, адже далі уточнення, що і кому належатиме.